# Change the build path for obj files

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-code, directory-structure

I recently downloaded the C/C++ extension for vs code, following this [tutorial](http://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-msvc) on setting it up for windows. I managed to figure out how to change the build path for the executable but I can't figure out how to change the build path for the `.obj` and `vc140.pdb` files.

This is the directory structure I would like to end up with once I build and run the program:
[image: directory]

Right now the `.obj` and the `vc140.pdb` files end up in the root of my directory but I would like to place them under the obj folder as shown above.

This is my current `tasks.json` file:

```
{
 "version": "2.0.0",
 "tasks": [
    {
        "type": "shell",
        "label": "C/C++: cl.exe build active file",
        "command": "cl.exe",
        "args": [
            "/Zi",
            "/EHsc",
            "/Fe:",
            "${workspaceFolder}\\bin\\debug\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",
            "${file}"
        ],
        "options": {
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
        },
        "problemMatcher": [
            "$msCompile"
        ],
        "group": {
            "kind": "build",
            "isDefault": true
        }
     }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution to my problem after going through the [command line arguments for the msvc compiler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/compiler-options-listed-alphabetically?view=vs-2019)

I had to add a [`/Fd`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/fd-program-database-file-name?view=vs-2019) and a [`/Fo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/fo-object-file-name?view=vs-2019) argument to correctly configure the build path for the `pdb` and `obj` files.

If anyone is interested in the `tasks.json`, here it is:

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "shell",
            "label": "C/C++: cl.exe build active file",
            "command": "cl.exe",
            "args": [
                "/Zi",
                "/EHsc",
                "/Fe:",
                "${workspaceFolder}\\bin\\debug\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",
                "/Fd:",
                "${workspaceFolder}\\obj\\debug\\vc140.pdb",
                "/Fo:",
                "${workspaceFolder}\\obj\\debug\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.obj",
                "${file}"
                
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$msCompile"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            }
        }
    ]
}
```