# How do I change the build paths for obj and pdb files in vscode?

Tags: c++, json, visual-studio-code, visual-c++, compiler-errors

I'm just trying to change the location of where the .obj and .pdb files are saved when compiling to keep things organized (into an obj folder), I'm trying to learn how this works, I am new to C++.

I looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64017655/change-the-build-path-for-obj-files?newreg=a0eaaa93f9be42a0b60b85e6eb452c54) and tried their solution, but I kept getting errors. I do what the errors tell me and it still does not compile properly. What am I doing wrong? I can get a bin folder to generate, not an obj for other files.

[image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TuP2O.png)

[image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uI10L.png)

Comment: Please paste your code as text instead of an image.

Comment: Most command line arguments in msvc won't end in a colon. I don't think the `/Fe: `  ... from the other question is even correct. Here is an example from Microsoft: [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/fe-name-exe-file?view=msvc-170#examples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/fe-name-exe-file?view=msvc-170#examples)